# predicting time series with support vector machine using R

Tags: r, time-series, machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I am planning to do time series prediction using support vector Machine. I could not find any materials about time series application of support vector machines using R or Mat-lab. Similar question was asked earlier but no answer.It would be great if anybody can help to solve this issue with some examples.

Thanks

Comment: You can try to use google... http://lmgtfy.com/?q=time-series+forecasting+svm
By the way, look at this arXiv paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.6613.pdf or at any paper or tutorial about time-series forecasting with black-box models...

Comment: Thank you Matteo. But my problem is that i couldn't find out any example problem done by using SVR in time series. I have data set , but don't have any approach model using R or Matlab.I tried SVR using kernal function in R. but dont know how to apply in ts. and is it possible to do multi step ahead prediction using SVR in ts??

Comment: Have a look at the Hyndman book on time-series forecasting here: https://www.otexts.org/book/fpp
He explains a neural network based approach, given that both a NN and SVM are black-box approaches, you can easily extend the book's examples to SVMs...

Comment: What is the type of time series problem are you trying to solve ? is it univariate or multivariate? If it is univariate there is no empirical evidence to support the use of SVM to improve accuracy over existing simpler statistical extrapolation methods.

Comment: @forecaster, I have seen Univariate time series using SVM in [link](http://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:386413/FULLTEXT01.pdf) (page 34). when i am doing the same experiment couldn't replicate the above result. [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137688/time-series-forecasting-using-support-vector-machines?noredirect=1#comment269185_137688) do u have any examples?